# In SQL, how will you distribute the deduction to each row based on each row's capacity?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, common-table-expression

I have  a table in sql that has the following columns. First table shows the quantity that was received and the second table is the quantity that was shipped. The 2nd table gives us a total of Qty 70 for SKU 1 and QTY 60 for SKU 2.

```
Received Table
Id  Sku Quantity
1   1   30       
2   1   20
3   1   100
4   2   600

Shipped Table
Id  Sku  Quantity 
1   1    50
2   1    20
3   2    60
```

I need a view that shows how much quantity were shipped relative to the received table. Now I want to distribute the total of each SKU in every row in this table that should give me the following result:

```
ID   Sku   Quantity   Used    Remaining
1    1     30         30      0
2    1     20         20      0
3    1     100        20      80
4    2     600        60      540
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes you're right. It's an incrementing integer. Let me change the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need cumulative sums and aggregation.  The following does a cumulative sum of quantity along with the total shipped in one row:

```
select r.*, cume.cumequantity, coalesce(s.shipped ,0)
from received r cross apply
     (select sum(r2.quantity) as cumequantity
      from received r2
      where r2.sku  = r.sku and r2.id <= r.id
     ) cume left join
     (select s.sku, sum(quantity) as shipped
      from shipped s
      group by s.sku
     ) s
     on r.sku = s.sku
```

This provides the basic information you need to answer your question.  The rest is just arithmetic and logic:

```
with rs as (
      select r.*, cume.cumequantity, coalesce(s.shipped ,0)
      from received r cross apply
           (select sum(r2.quantity) as cumequantity
            from received r2
            where r2.sku  = r.sku and r2.id <= r.id
           ) cume left join
           (select s.sku, sum(quantity) as shipped
            from shipped s
            group by s.sku
           ) s
           on r.sku = s.sku
     )
select rs.ID, rs.Sku, rs.Quantity,
       (case when rs.cumequantity <= rs.shipped
             then rs.quantity
             when rs.cumquantity > rs.shipped and
                  rs.cumquantity - rs.quantity < rs.shipped
             then rs.shipped - rs.cumquantity - rs.quantity
             else 0
        end) as used,
       (case when rs.cumequantity <= rs.shipped
             then 0
             when rs.cumequantity > rs.shipped and
                  rs.cumequantity - rs.quantity < rs.shipped
             then rs.quantity - (rs.shipped - rs.cumequantity - rs.quantity)
             else rs.quantity
        end) as remaining
from rs
```